# Non-HTTP traffic on port 80 across Cisco load balancer

Tags: cisco, load-balancing, http, port

Is it possible to configure port 80 on a Cisco load balancer as being general TCP, rather than specifically HTTP, in order to support more protocols on that port?

I am attempting to get Websockets working through the balancer but see behaviour suggesting it prevents non-HTTP traffic on port 80 by default.

Comment: What Cisco load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the Cisco ACE load balancers?

And, yes... As mentioned this is fully possible. Although Cisco ACE does not have any specific knowledge of the WebSocket protocols, it can be set up to do generic Connection based Level 3 and 4 load balancing. I have successfully done this myself using information from the following manual page:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/app_ntwk_services/data_center_app_services/ace_appliances/vA3_1_0/configuration/slb/guide/classlb.html

It provides examples for load balancing of many protocols, plus information on generic TCP/IP (Level 3 and 4) connection loadbalancing (which I used).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, but I doubt it supports the Websockets protocol. Support (for Websockets) in leading load-balance solutions (which many say Cisco isn't) has only arrived in the last month or so and, as a result, I suspect that's the cause of your issue.